# Rundeck Version Control with Ansible

Tags: git, ansible, rundeck

My goal is to be able to run ansible playbooks in Rundeck that are in a version control. Is there a way/plugin that allows Ansible code be version controlled inside Rundeck so I can create jobs based on the location of my repos? I`ve looked at the SCM option but it seems that is only for running jobs.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Rundeck Workflow that involves a git repository check before execute an Ansible Playbook. [This](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/git-plugin) Rundeck plugin should helps. So, the workflow could be: 1) check the repo, 2) get the ansible playbook file, and 3) execute the ansible playbook file by using the rundeck ansible steps.

Of course, you can replace the plugin behavior by manual git check via script step.